# Assigning value to array by logical indexing doesn't work

Tags: arrays, matlab

In Matlab, I want to replace a certain value with some other value.

I know that I can do this:

```
X(X==0) = -1
```

If I want to replace all occurrences of 0s to 1.

I have an array X that contains digits that range between 0 to 9. I want to create a new array Y where the ith value of Y is 1 if X(i) == some given digit, say 5, and otherwise -1. So I wrote a code:

```
Y = (X == 5); 
Y(Y==0) = -1;
```

The first line works fine. It projects all cells with '5' to 1 otherwise 0 because it's a logic operation. Then if it's 0, I want to replace it with -1, but the second line somehow makes all value of the array to 1. Does anyone have insight why this would happen?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why your approach was not working is indeed a little curios. The reason is that the left hand side of your equation is completely logical, the right hand side is casted logical as well and

```
logical(-1) = 1
```

Therefore:

```
Y = (X == 5)    %// Y is logical
Y(Y == 0) = -1  %// Y is logical, Y == 0 is logical, 
                %// -1 is casted to logical and logical(-1) = 1
```

So transform your first logical array to double, and it works.

```
Y = (X == 5)    %// Y is logical
Y = double(Y)   %// Y is double
Y(Y == 0) = -1  %// Y is double, Y == 0 is logical
```

---

**Example:**

```
X = randi(9,20,1);
Y = (X == 5)   
Y = double(Y)   
Y(Y == 0) = -1  
out = [X Y]
```

---

```
out =

     7    -1
     3    -1
     5     1
     7    -1
     9    -1
     9    -1
     5     1
     2    -1
     2    -1
     3    -1
     8    -1
     3    -1
     8    -1
     3    -1
     9    -1
     4    -1
     2    -1
     3    -1
     6    -1
     5     1
```

Comment: @beaker that doesn' matter

Comment: yeah, just figured that out... :)

Comment: I think the reason why the original approach doesn't work is: when `Y` is a `logical` array, assigning a value other than 0 or 1 to some of its entries doesn't make it a `double`;  it remains as `logical`. So everything other than `0` is cast to logical `1` (`true`), and `0` is cast to logical `0` (`false`). Try this for example: `y = true, y(1) = -1`

Comment: `Y = (X == 5)*2 - 1` also works, I guess because the multiplication converts the entire array to numeric.

Comment: @LuisMendo I was writing this into the answer, while you wrote this comment. I agree!